# Planning a trip, which breweries should I go to?

Tags: commercial, brewery, brewpub

Sorry if this is considered off-topic, but I'm planning a trip from Philly to Outer Banx in NC next week.  I'm starting to look at my route now, and was curious if any of you out there had any brewery suggestions for me to hit up on the way down.

I'll definitely be hitting Dogfish head in DE and possibly Clipper City (Heavy Seas) in MD if it's not too far out of the way.

Anything else?

EDIT: I should mention that I live in Philly now, so I've been to at least most of the local breweries.

Comment: Great question, I'm going to OBX in 2 weeks and am wondering the same thing.

Comment: This question is better suited for Beer Advocate, or one of the other sites dedicated to commercial breweries. Voted to close.

Comment: The criteria for questions on the site is "for dedicated home brewers and serious enthusiasts".  I would say that wanting to tour a good microbrewery and learn their process is an enthusiast-type question.  If it is indeed off topic the FAQ should be updated to reflect that and give a better definition of what can and can't be asked...I think I hear a new meta topic being born.

Comment: @Hopwise I can understand your logic, however I went for homebrewers on purpose. Just as Room3 suggested, I'm very interested in the brewing process which, at least in my opinion, could keep this on topic. Also, I'm looking for the same thing I do while I homebrew: to drink new and delicious beer! Isn't that why we all do it?

Comment: At least make this wiki. There isn't an answer to this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm planning on going to the [Weeping Radish Brewery](http://www.weepingradish.com/) (the oldest microbrewery in North Carolina).  All the beer drinkers I know that have gone to the Outer Banks recommend it.  There's also a place called the Corolla Brewpub that I plan on visiting.

If you're passing through Richmond there's the Lengend Brewery and quite a few brewpubs.

Around Norfolk/Virginia Beach area there's a Gordon Biersch.

Answer (score 1):

Boulevard in KC is a good one... out of your way,, but a good one!

Answer (score 1):

Victory is in Downingtown, PA. They just released a new golden ale called Summer Love this past Monday. You can also try their root beer. It is excellent.

Answer (score 1):

There's Duck Rabbit in Farmington, NC.  I'm not sure where that is in relation to OBX, though.

Edit: Whoops, it's in FarmVILLE, NC, which is considerably closer.

Comment: just the fact that it is in a town called Farmville makes me unsure haha.

Answer (score 0):

Should this go another direction and become more of a wiki article about brewery visits, I can recommend:

- Oskar Blues in Longmont, CO
- Left Hand in Longmont, CO
- Sweetwater in Atlanta, GA

Until the brewery laws change, you won't want to visit any breweries in Alabama - it's illegal for them to serve any beer - even samples.

Answer (score 0):

Clipper City Brewing, which brews [Heavy Seas](http://www.hsbeer.com), is in Baltimore.